# TreeView with unlimited nodes

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, treeview

I want to make treeview with unlimited nodes. I have 2 viewmodel for tree:

```
public class GroupViewModel
{
    public GroupViewModel()
    {
    }

    public string GroupName { get; set; }

    public ObservableCollection<TagViewModel> Tags { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<GroupViewModel> Groups { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class TagViewModel
{
    public TagViewModel()
    {
    }

    public string TagName { get; set; }
}
```

My XAML:

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModel:GroupViewModel}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Tags}">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=GroupName}" />
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModel:TagViewModel}">
    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <CheckBox />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=TagName}" Margin="5,0,0,0" />
    </StackPanel>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>

TreeView Name="groupsTreeView"></TreeView>
```

With

> ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Tags}"

i have first-level group with tags

and with

> ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Groups}"

i have groups with subgroups - without tags.

How i can make tree with groups and tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each tree node can only use one collection as items source for its children.
You have at least two options to combine groups and tags in a single collection:

- Change your ViewModel to have Groups and Tags in a single ObservableCollection
- Use a [CompositeCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.compositecollection.aspx) to combine two collections in your XAML